# Destroying dynamically allocated memory in omnetpp responsibility

Tags: c++, memory-management, simulation, omnet++

Using Omnet++ to create some switch simulation,
I'm using cPacket encapsulation & decapsulation methodology.

My question is, which module, or in what part destroying of dynamically allocated memory should occur in such cases.

For example, lets say I have the following module, which creates a packet encapsulated in another cPacket, and sends it to other module:

```
void X::initialize()
{
    cPacket* packet = new cPacket("packet");
    cPacket* encapsulated = new cPacket("encapsulated");

    packet->encapsulate(encapsulated);
    send(packet, "XtoYout")
}
```

Logically thinking, I thought the decapsulating module is responsible for deleting the encapsulated packet:

```
void Y::handleMessage(cPacket* msg)
{
    cPacket* overlay_packet = msg->decapsulate();
    /* DO SOMETHING */

    delete msg;
    delete overlay_packet;
}
```

But according to Omnet++ documentation, `decapsulate()` provides us with a memory duplication, so the *originally allocated memory* for `encapsulated` isn't really destroyed:

*Taken from omnet simulation manual - [Reference Counting](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:messages:reference-counting)*

> **5.4.5 Reference Counting**
>
> Since the 3.2 release, OMNeT++ implements reference counting of
>   encapsulated packets, meaning that if you dup() a packet that contains
>   an encapsulated packet, then the encapsulated packet will not be
>   duplicated, only a reference count incremented. **Duplication of the**
>   **encapsulated packet is deferred *until decapsulate()* actually gets**
>   **called**. If the outer packet is deleted without its decapsulate()
>   method ever being called, then the reference count of the encapsulated
>   packet is simply decremented. The encapsulated packet is deleted when
>   its reference count reaches zero.

Also, it is not clear if when encapsulating in the first place, the encapsulated packet is cloned (so we can delete the allocated memory already at `X::initialize()`, after using `packet->encapsulated(...)`.

Documentation is a bit vague, but I think it means the the original address of `encapsulated` is pointed in the cPacket when encapsulating, so I can't delete in `X::initialize()` :

*Taken from Omnet++ cPacket class reference - [cPacket encapsulate(..)](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp4/api/classcPacket.html#a60f2a48bf1d777342394acd3ddf9fbf3)*

> virtual void cPacket::encapsulate (   cPacket *   packet   )  [virtual]
>   Encapsulates packet in the packet.
>
> The packet length gets increased by the length of the encapsulated
>   packet.
>
> IMPORTANT NOTE: IT IS FORBIDDEN TO KEEP A POINTER TO A MESSAGE AFTER
>   IT WAS ENCAPSULATED. For performance reasons, encapsulated packets are
>   reference counted, meaning that the encapsulated packet is not
>   duplicated when you duplicate a packet, but rather, both (all) copies
>   share the same packet instance. Any change done to the encapsulated
>   packet would affect other packets as well. Decapsulation (and even
>   calling getEncapsulatedPacket()) will create an own (non-shared) copy
>   of the packet.

So, to conclude:

**What is the correct place \ flow to destroy the allocated memory for `cPacket* encapsulated`?**

Comment: It is in the documentation snippet you copied: "The encapsulated packet is deleted when its reference count reaches zero."
So I think when you decapsulate it, you get a copy, and the reference count of the original packet drops to zero, so it will be deleted. But you could just check it yourself by putting some print statements to the constructors/destructor of a custom packet class, or even a static instance counter.

Comment: I believe you are correct, probably missed that. Thanks